# Higher concurrency vs lower concurrency

Tags: rest, concurrency

In doing a load test (by using Siege for example) for servers, is a lower concurrency number better?

What does this number signify?

Answer (score 1):

The Siege docs go into detail on concurrency here: https://www.joedog.org/2012/02/17/concurrency-single-siege/

From that page:

> The calculation is simple: total transactions divided by elapsed time. If we did 100 transactions in 10 seconds, then our concurrency was 10.00.

Higher concurrency measure CAN mean that your server is handling more connections faster but it can also mean that your server is falling behind on calculations and causing connections to be queued. So your concurrency measure is only valuable when taken in context of time elapsed.